# Meaning of "like growing up"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of *like growing up* in the following sentence?

> Now, you grew up in Southern California. What was it **like growing up**
>   on the beach in the summer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should cut the meaning chunks this way:

What was it like + growing up on the beach?

The expression "What is it like?" is used to ask "How is it?"

Ex.

1. What's he like?
2. What's the new place like?
3. What's it like having a lot of kids?

Comment: Yes, or phrased another way, "What was it like to have grown up on the beach?"

Answer (score 0):

Now, you grew up in Southern California.  What was it like growing up on the beach in the summer?

When we ask 'What was it like?' we are assuming the person we are speaking to has knowledge of something and we want to find out about it.

Look at the following:

What is John like?  He is a thoughtful person.
(This is different to 'What does he look like?' This is asking for a description of physical characteristics.)

What was the film like?  It was interesting.